# Why does Chrome sometimes automatically tweet when I start Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, twitter

Say I posted a tweet with the latest version of Google Chrome yesterday, and today when I start Chrome again it will post that tweet again in the background. Why does it do that and how can I stop it?

It happens sometimes, but not always... I'm guessing 1 out of 10 times.

Comment: You must report the same to Google on the link: https://support.google.com/chrome/

Comment: Also have you installed any particular app/extension for twitter on the browser ???

Comment: Do you have Chrome set to re-open your previous tabs when opened?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I do have extensions that are not Twitter related, but I only enable them when I need them so that shouldn't be the problem.

Indeed I have Chrome to re-open previous tabs, I forgot to mention that. My guess is that it's a caching issue. I will report it to Google and see what they have to say about it.